# How can I delete merge commit

Tags: git, workflow

In the following image you will see firstly the real situation and then the solution I would like to have

[image]

So I want to undo the merging done from B to A.

The problem is that everything was already pushed and the development went on with the branch C, and also I've done a new commit on A after merging it with B.

Is it possible to change this git situation to the second image or is a "reverse commit" the only way to go to correct the mistake?

#### what I did?

- revese the commit that was used to merge
- rebase branch C on the new commit from A
- force push the rebase made on C to change the remote branch too

But the resulting scheme I get doesn't look clear, that's why I'm seeking another answer

Comment: If the "what I did" section you just edited in is your solution, you should edit it out of the question and post it as an answer.

Comment: @DaveZych It's not the answer I'm looking for, I've done another edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Branch C looks like that:

```
...--a---------M--f--g--h--i--j
      \       /      ^        ^
       b--c--d      [A]      [C]
             ^
            [B]
```

First, you should rebase branch `C`:

```
git rebase --onto <sha-of-commit-a> B C
```

After this operation branch C should look like that:

```
a--f'--g'--h'--i'--j'
                   ^
                  [C]
```

Now is the time to update branch `A`:

```
git checkout A
git reset --hard <sha-of-commit-g'>
```

That's all. Your repository should look like this merge never happened.

Comment: great! I did test this on a sample git repository and it did work! but I will not do it in the "real" repository because too much has been going already since I've noticed this.